# How to make the following pairing?

Tags: random, filtering

Consider the following list of identifiers:

```
Npart=5000;
ilist=Range[1,Npart];
```

And parameters belonging to the given identifier:

```
energies = Join[RandomReal[{0.5,3.5},4900],RandomReal[{50,100},100]];
```

I need an algorithm that randomly selects `Npart/2` pairs of identifiers (each of the identifiers may be in pairs only once) based on the pair weight, which, for the given pair of identifiers `{i,j}`, is `energies[[i]]*energies[[j]]`.

Could you please tell me an efficient algorithm?

Comment: This is not terribly clear. You might want to give a much smaller example, with a desired output shown. Presumably "identifiers" are elements of the list 1...5000. Do you mean to use all the identifiers, each appearing in one of 2500 pairs? If so, since the weight measure is the product, picking a pair is equivalent to selecting two distinct ones at random, using the given weights. `RandomSample` will be the function to use then.

Comment: What I mean is something like this (not sure it's what you want though). `In[249]:= npart = 50;
ilist = Range[npart];
energies = 
  Join[RandomReal[{0.5, 3.5}, 9/10*npart], 
   RandomReal[{500, 1000}, npart/10]];
In[252]:= pairs = Partition[RandomSample[energies -> ilist], 2]
Out[252]= {{47,49}, {50,48}, {46,12}, {2,28}, {23,8}, {7, 36}, {38,24}, {19,27}, {26,18}, {20,6}, {35,15}, {34,31}, {37,5}, {41,10}, {14,25}, {13,30}, {44,40}, {4,33}, {17,11}, {39,3}, {42,21}, {32,22}, {9,1}, {29,45}, {43,16}}` The much higher weights were the last 5, so items 46-50 appear at the beginning.