# How to speed up the following algorithm?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, random

I have some random combinations of numbers `pairs` (where numbers range from `1` to some `ntest`) and weights to them `weights`, merged into `weightspairs`. I need to generate `n/2` fully distinct pairs (such that each number is repeated in the generated set only once) using `RandomSample/RandomChoice`.

I do this iteratively: generate the random combination, remove all occurrences of the numbers from the random combination from `weightspairs`, and repeat:

```
ntest = 100;
pairs = Subsets[Range[ntest] // N, {2}] // Developer`ToPackedArray;
weights = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[pairs]];
weightspairs = Join[Partition[weights, 1], pairs, 2];
Do[
  generatedPairsStep = 
   RandomSample[weightspairs[[All, 1]] -> weightspairs, 1];
  If[i == 1,
   pairssampling = generatedPairsStep,
   pairssampling = Join[pairssampling, generatedPairsStep];
   ];
  nlist = Drop[pairssampling, 1];
  nlist = Flatten[pairssampling[[All, {2, 3}]]] // Sort;
  matchesNList[row_] := 
   MemberQ[nlist, row[[2]]] || MemberQ[nlist, row[[3]]];
  weightspairs = DeleteCases[weightspairs, _?matchesNList];
  If[Length[weightspairs] == 0, Break[]]
  , {i, 1, ntest/2, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The method is slow, taking around ~1 second, and I need to consider a much larger `ntest`. It is clear that some part of the code may be compiled, but the problem is that the approach itself is not optimal, especially in the part `DeleteCases`.

Could you please tell me how to speed it up?

**Edit**

The following code works much faster, although it is still algorithmically poor (the time scales as `ntest^3`):

```
compiledsel = 
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {nlist, _Real, 1}}, 
   Select[data, ! MemberQ[nlist, #[[2]]] && ! 
       MemberQ[nlist, #[[3]]] &], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];
ntest = 400;
pairs = Subsets[Range[ntest] // N, {2}] // 
    Developer`ToPackedArray; // AbsoluteTiming
weights = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[pairs]];
weightspairs = Join[Partition[weights, 1], pairs, 2];
nseed = ntest/2;
Do[
  generatedPairsStep = 
   RandomChoice[weightspairs[[All, 1]] -> weightspairs, nseed] // 
    RandomSample;
  par = {{}};
  nTempList = {};
  Do[If[! MemberQ[nTempList, generatedPairsStep[[m]][[2]]] && ! 
       MemberQ[nTempList, generatedPairsStep[[m]][[3]]],
     par = Join[par, {generatedPairsStep[[m]]}];
     nTempList = Join[nTempList, Drop[generatedPairsStep[[m]], 1]]];
   , {m, 1, nseed, 1}];
  If[i == 1,
   pairssampling = Drop[par, 1],
   pairssampling = Join[pairssampling, Drop[par, 1]];
   ];
  nlist = nTempList;
  weightspairs = 
   compiledsel[weightspairs, nlist] // Developer`ToPackedArray;
  If[Length[weightspairs] == 0, Break[]]
  , {i, 1, ntest/2, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Here, however, I sample the pairs not one-by-one, but a much larger amount of times.

Comment: You don't need the `// N` on the second line - they're just integers.

Comment: Given your other recent questions. It sounds like you just want to do something like this. Though this minimizes weight instead of maximizes it, you could invert your weights:
`g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ pairs, EdgeWeight -> weights]; FindEdgeCover[g]`

Comment: @flinty : if not converting to N, the matrix would not be a packed array, whixh slows down the calculations.

Comment: Is this different from what I commented on in [one of several similar prior posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/299694/how-to-make-the-following-pairing)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : yes, the weight may be generic, and in particular it kay be some non-trivial product of the quantities belonging to the pair.

Comment: @JohnTaylor I don't know why you think that: [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/ToPackedArray.html) says it accepts integers.

Comment: @flinty : I mean that the mixed integer and numeric numbers do not form a packed array: `{1, 2, 3.} // Developer`PackedArrayQ` returns false. In my code, I would operate with such arrays without converting integer numbers to numeric.

Comment: @flinty : thanks! This is elegant. However, it is also much slower than the revised approach from my question and the code proposed by Daniel Lichtblau.

Comment: @flinty : also, `FindEdgeCover` produces not `n/2` pairs but a slightly larger number, so there are repetitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the weights are based on pairs rather than separably based on individual elements, you can take a random sample of the full set of pairs by weights and sequentially remove each that has an element already used. This save the time of sequential removals interleaved with selections.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ntest = 100;
 pairs = Subsets[Range[ntest] // N, {2}] // Developer`ToPackedArray;
 weights = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[pairs]];
 weightspairs = Join[Partition[weights, 1], pairs, 2];
 generated = RandomSample[weightspairs[[All, 1]] -> weightspairs];
 reduced = 
  Map[If[TrueQ[seen[#[[2]]]] || TrueQ[seen[#[[3]]]], 
     Nothing, (Map[(seen[#] = True) &, Rest@#]; #)] &, generated];
 ClearAll[seen];
 reduced]

(* Out[291]= {0.010269, {{0.938872, 26., 75.}, {0.526988, 7., 
   95.}, {0.828101, 6., 45.}, {0.534685, 31., 94.}, {0.117848, 8., 
   15.}, {0.507512, 61., 71.}, {0.458398, 37., 80.}, {0.998765, 3., 
   38.}, {0.92762, 16., 85.}, {0.515526, 18., 52.}, {0.194932, 23., 
   86.}, {0.600985, 1., 97.}, {0.964535, 24., 50.}, {0.870533, 27., 
   83.}, {0.56242, 22., 40.}, {0.842291, 13., 46.}, {0.718279, 19., 
   25.}, {0.401877, 76., 93.}, {0.933245, 34., 87.}, {0.0881186, 2., 
   30.}, {0.614855, 4., 63.}, {0.721995, 11., 33.}, {0.339263, 69., 
   77.}, {0.655064, 21., 73.}, {0.502061, 57., 66.}, {0.969345, 60., 
   100.}, {0.0779854, 29., 55.}, {0.639042, 9., 62.}, {0.784737, 41., 
   70.}, {0.458987, 17., 68.}, {0.662033, 10., 48.}, {0.766491, 47., 
   49.}, {0.940952, 51., 53.}, {0.638249, 79., 91.}, {0.662277, 42., 
   74.}, {0.319627, 72., 90.}, {0.580323, 12., 78.}, {0.682557, 5., 
   56.}, {0.432495, 67., 81.}, {0.829214, 36., 43.}, {0.73324, 20., 
   82.}, {0.961731, 28., 32.}, {0.254803, 44., 54.}, {0.575702, 58., 
   88.}, {0.297704, 14., 64.}, {0.874084, 84., 98.}, {0.507488, 39., 
   65.}, {0.425491, 89., 96.}, {0.927165, 59., 99.}, {0.563442, 35., 
   92.}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach works somewhat faster than my revised approach (in the edit of the question). In particular, it seems to have a better scaling of time with `ntest`.

Comment: It should be roughly quadratic in `ntest`.

Answer (score 2):

Random as in "each result should be equally likely"? Then you could sample a random subset of length `2 n` with `RandomSample` and then apply an `RandomPermutation`. Afterwards, apply `Partition[#,2]&`:

```
Partition[
 Part[
  RandomSample[Range[1, ntest], 2 n],
  PermutationList[RandomPermutation[n], n]
  ],
 2
 ]
```